# Not able to checkout from a locally created git branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-checkout

I created a new branch using :

`git checkout -b DikshaPython`

---

Now I am not able to checkout from the branch and move back to master.
Even when I close the window of gitBash and open it again it shows that I am still on this branch.
I have used commands

`git fetch`
`git checkout`
and nothing happens. I have even tried to force delete the branch by using `git branch -D DikshaPython`
and I get and error

> "error: Cannot delete branch 'DikshaPython' checked out at 'C:/Users/Diksha Nasa'"

---

Searched stack overflow and found some answers which recommended using `$ git checkout master`
`$ git branch -d DikshaPython`
Recieved an error

> error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git

---

Please help me as to how do I get back to my master branch, I have not stored anything on this branch so deleting it is not an issue.

Comment: Use `git branch` to list all available branches. Then  `git checkout [branch name]` to move to that branch. Also, I may be wrong, but I think you have a misconception that `git checkout [branch name]` "checks out" from that given branch and puts you in master. `git checkout ` actually switches **to** the specified  branch name.

Comment: Hey, I tried using ```git branch``` and the only branch I got is DikshaPython . I tried ```git checkout master``` to get back to the master branch, hoping it would switch me to the master branch ,but received an error "error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git". I am very new to git so maybe I messed up in understanding the commands. Please guide me how to proceed now.

Comment: Either there was never a master branch or you deleted it or renamed it. Use git reflog to get more of a sense of what you did. If there was a master branch we may be able to restore it.

Comment: Also please do `git branch --all -vv`

Comment: What does ```git branch -a``` returns in your case? Please, add this to the question.

Comment: @matt ```git reflog``` gives the output "0eb77ae (HEAD -> DikshaPython) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from DikshaPython to DikshaPython
0eb77ae (HEAD -> DikshaPython) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
0eb77ae (HEAD -> DikshaPython) HEAD@{2}: commit (initial): Initial commit."  and ```git branch --all -vv``` gives "* DikshaPython 0eb77ae Initial commit."

Comment: @smmehrab ```git branch -a``` outputs "* DikshaPython"

Comment: Hmm, does `git reflog --all` mention any other branches? If not, maybe master never existed. It seems you have just one branch and one commit and that's all there ever was?

Comment: @matt Someone answered(in this question itself) that creating a branch master might resolve the problem. But I have now actually ended up adding another branch master and now have entered that. I just want to restore my Gitbash to where it was before I messed up with branches. "Diksha Nasa@LAPTOP-1NOBF8F8 MINGW64 ~ (master)" This is what I see in my Git bash now(after creating master, before instead of master it was showing DikshaPython).

Comment: Before you created the branch there was nothing. The repo was empty. Is that what you want? If so just throw the whole folder away and start over.

Comment: @matt I probably think it would be best for me to just start over. I deleted the folder of the cloned repo but that doesn't seem to solve it. Please guide me what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

If you are branching, you must consider a few points:

- You must know the branch names
- You must know the most important git branching commands
- And at least, also dominate `git merge`, to bring branches back together

To find out all *branch names*, execute `git branch` (to show also all remote branch, write `git branch -a`). The output will be as follow:

```
# branch1
  branch2
  branch3
```

The branch with the `#` is the branch, where you now stay. To change the branch, as example `branch3`, type `git checkout branch3`.

The output from `git branch` will now looks like this:

```
# branch3
  branch1
  branch2
```

So first check the *branch names* and then checkout one existing branch. I guess, because you have the `github` tag, that it is a GitHub repository. And in GitHub repository isn‘t a `master` branch if you make the *Quick Setup* on the GitHub website, there is the `main` branch.

Comment: Using ```git branch``` gives the output "* DikshaPython" and yes, it is a GitHub repository that I am working on, and this is the first time I created a branch. When I open my GitBash "Diksha Nasa@LAPTOP-1NOBF8F8 MINGW64 ~ (DikshaPython)" this is what I see, showing I am in the DikshaPython branch (I could be wrong) but I want to get back to when it did not show the branch name.

Comment: "I want to get back to when it did not show the branch name" But that was not because you were on master but because you had no commits yet, perhaps. It's odd that if this is a GitHub repo you seem to have no tracking branches. It seems like this repo is not actually hooked to any GitHub repo. Did you ever `git clone`? Or `git remote add origin <url>`?

Answer (score 0):

So by the comment, I assume you somehow never had a master branch or you might have renamed it.
Anyways, To create a new branch and switch to it at the same time, you can run the `git checkout` command with the `-b` switch:

```
$ git checkout -b master
$ Switched to a new branch "master"
```

This is the shorthand of creating a branch first, and then switching to it:

```
git branch master
git checkout master
```

Comment: This just created another branch called "master" and now I have gotten in that branch but I want to just leave all branches and restore my GitBash to where it was before I messed up with the branches.

Comment: @DikshaNasa , May I know how exactly did you get the git repository? Did you clone it? Or did you run `git init` from scratch?

Comment: I cloned the repo.

Comment: @DikshaNasa , My best guess would be that the cloned repository never had a `master` branch